# Can the result of a function call be used as a default parameter value?

Tags: c++, parameters, default-value

Is there a good method for writing C / C++ function headers with default parameters that are function calls?

I have some header with the function:

```
int foo(int x, int y = 0);
```

I am working in a large code base where many functions call this function and depend on this default value. This default value now needs to change to something dynamic and I am looking for a way to do:

```
int foo(int x, int y = bar());
```

Where bar() is some function that generates the default value based on some system parameters. Alternatively this function prototype would look like:

```
int foo(int x, int y = baz.bar());
```

Where baz is a function belonging to an object that has not been instantiated within the header file.

Comment: AFAIK this is relevant for C++ not C (C does not support default values).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go figure!  It does work. [Default arguments in C++ functions](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc/language/ref/cplr237.htm)

Answer (score 7):

I would use two overloaded functions:

`int foo(int x, int y);`

`int foo(int x){return foo(x,bar);}`

If you allow the forwarding function to be inlined, then the performance penalty is likely to small to zero. If you keep the body of it out of line in a non-header file there may be a performance cost (likely to be small), but much more flexibility in implementation and reduced coupling.

Comment: The suggestion on using overloaded functions is good, but the code in the questoin does work as-is.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. What you've written works.

Comment: Really?  I never would have thought.

Comment: Lol. I downvoted this as obviously wrong before trying it out myself.

Comment: Been programming C++ for 8 years and did not know this!

Comment: I keep discovering new things about C++ all the time :-)

Answer (score 6):

What's wrong with simply removing the optional parameter in the first declaration and providing a single parameter overload?

```
int foo(int x)
{
    Bar bar = //whatever initialization
    return foo(x,bar.baz());
}

int foo(int x,int y)
{
  //whatever the implementation is right now
}
```

I think this tends to be much cleaner and more flexible than trying to use some dynamic default value.

Answer (score 4):

In the standard, section 8.3.6 (Default arguments), paragraph 5, they give an example using just this approach. Specifically, it calls out that default arguments are *expressions*, so a function call applies, albeit with restrictions such as name lookup and type compatibility.

In my workplace, we've used signatures like this:

```
void An_object::An_object(
  const Foo &a,
  const Bar &b,
  const Strategem &s = Default_strategem()
);
```

to allow clients to override a behavior in a class constructor. It came in handy for conditional behavior which affected performance of a translator...

Answer (score 2):

Tangential, but that looks to me like it'd introduce dependence issues down the road. I'd go with stbuton.myopenid.com's approach.

Answer (score 1):

It should be perfectly valid to call a global function or reference a global object in this context, as long as the declaration of the function/object is in scope. It may or may not be advisable (in terms of good design), but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try making bar() a static member function.  This will allow any part of the program which has such a static class in scope to access it.  For example:

class Foo
{
public:

static int bar();
};

Then you would declare:

int foo(int x, int y = Foo::bar());

If you need different objects then pass in the instance of the object instead.